# How to query using a string in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ and I was Originally searching by the Primary Key in the table.  However, now since I need to pass the my search fields through numerous pages (which makes the URL very large).  I want to fix this by changing from passing Guids between pages to passing the Strings between pages.  This is what I had prior:

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(Guid? createdById)
{
     var model = db.Knowledgebases.AsQueryable();

     if (createdById != null & createdById != Guid.Empty)
     {
           model = model.Where(k => k.CreatedById == createdById);
           ViewBag.CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserId == createdById).First().FullName;
           ViewBag.CreatedById = createdById;
     }
     model = model.OrderBy(k => k.CreatedDate);
     var result = model.ToList();

     return View(result);
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do now:

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(string? createdBy)
{
     var model = db.Knowledgebases.AsQueryable();

     if (createdBy != null)
     {
          model = model.Where(c => c.CreatedBy.FullName == createdBy);
          ViewBag.CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName == createdBy).First().FullName;
          ViewBag.CreatedBy = createdBy;
     }
     model = model.OrderBy(k => k.CreatedDate);
     var result = model.ToList();

     return View(result);
}
```

As you can see I am passing in a sting now (that can be empty). However, I am getting the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string?'

Comment: `string?` doesn't make sense because it is a reference type. Just leave the `?` away.

Comment: `string? createdBy` compiles?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah I was not getting an error on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have discovered that there is no operator overload for `==` between a string and a nullable string.

In any case, a nullable string makes no sense, as a plain old string is already nullable. Change your method's signature to

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(string createdBy)
```

And it will all work as expected, you can still pass `null` or an empty string to your method as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to wrap `string` as `Nullable` type, as it is by default:

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(string? createdBy)
```

Simply leave the `?` out and you're fine:

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(string createdBy)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose c.UserId is string? When checking string, you should use string.IsNullOrEmpty(string value). Don't use "==" on strings, use

```
public ActionResult TechKnowledgebaseList(Guid? createdBy)
{
     string crBy = Guid.GetValueOrDefault(/*some default value or nothing*/).ToString();

     var model = db.Knowledgebases.AsQueryable();

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(crBy)))
     {
          model = model.Where(c => c.CreatedBy.FullName == createdBy);
          ViewBag.CreatedBy = db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName.Equals(crBy)).First().FullName;
          ViewBag.CreatedBy = createdBy;
     }
     model = model.OrderBy(k => k.CreatedDate);
     var result = model.ToList();

     return View(result);
}
```